# Write to a file binary in Xcode

Tags: cocoa-touch, binary

I want to create a struct or object and then save it in a file,but I'm confused for do it.
Do you show the steps?

I have tried to use the writeToFile method, but it isn't a good solution for me because I want to write a structured file,where there are various fields(name,surname,bool field ...).

I don't want to use a database

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is to create a NSDictionary or NSMutabledictionary (which contains key/value pairings) and then write it out to a file.  Here is a quick and dirty sample.

First define your NSDictionary...

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *someInfo;
```

Then the following function will look for the file. If the file exist, it will read it into the NSDictionary; and if the file does not exist, it will create it and write it out.  You will probably want to use a NSMutabledictionary since you can change the values and keys after creation.  Also, be careful with saving values other than strings (or nill).  You can call this function from ViewDidLoad...

```
- (void)readDictionary {
// check to see if the file exist

NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)
                    objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *docFilePath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"saveinfo.plist"];

NSFileManager *filemgr;
filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:docFilePath]) {
    _someInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:docFilePath];
} else {
    _someInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"John", @"firstName",
                 @"Smith", @"lastName", nil];
    if (![_someInfo writeToFile:docFilePath atomically:YES]) {
        NSLog(@"Errro writing plist");
    }
}

//NSLog(@"%@", _someInfo);
}
```

Comment: thank for this solution but I think that it isn't good for me because in a single file I want to save a lot of things with the same fields; for example I want to save information about contacts(name,surname,number,married or no ...).For this reason I save one contact with the his information(name,surname,number,married or no ...) and then save in append other contact with other information(name,surname,number,married or no ...). I don't know if I was accurate

Comment: Then you may want to create an array of dictionarys, saving the array is very similar to saving the dictionary.